# SQLite UPDATE value with row number possible/options?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, bash

Hi i'm working on an SQLite viewer in android using java and shell commands (so commands have to be one line) i've written the layout and viewer and all everything is perfect. I set it up so when a value is long pressed an edit text shows where the user can input the new value and then when okay is pressed it should update the value.

I have the column name, old and new value, database name, table name etc however the issue is allowing them to update the value i've seen things like the where clause but the issue is if a column has the value multiple times (which could very well be the case) it won't know the correct row.

So bear in mind i'm new to sqlite been working with it less than a week. Is there a way i can update the column value with the columns name and row number?

What are my options to update the table.

I also don't really under stand this say i have a table like this (one column)

```
sample
--------
0
0
0
1
0
1
1
0
```

How would you update the third row to equal 1? If I did

```
sqlite3 DATABASEHERE "UPDATE TABLEHERE SET sample='1' WHERE sample='0'"
```

The where statement describes rows 1, 2, 3, 5, and 8 so there has to be a way to use row number?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you add the CREATE statement for the table?

Comment: You can't have a table like this. Relational Algebra (on which relational databases like SQLite are based) defines a relation (or table) as a set of tuples. Being a set, tuples with the exact same values are indistinguishable. It's not possible to have a number of rows with all the same values as they would be considered the same and thus only saved once.

Comment: I don't have a create statement i don't think i can get that since i'm not working with my database its working with any database it's part of a file browser i'm writing so i'm working on editing databases on like the sdcard and what not

Comment: as for the not being able to have a table like this i have one on my phone where 0 means to show notifications and 1 means to hide them so i see 0 multiple times and 1 multiple times depending on the preference (from superuser database)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SQLite gives you access to [rowid](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid). So you can write `SELECT rowid, col FROM table1` and then use it to update the table :`UPDATE TABLEHERE SET sample='1' WHERE rowid=3`